# How can I revert the effect of "stty cols N"?

Tags: terminal, stty

I have set `stty cols 72` in my `xterm` terminal.

How to unset it to normal? Because when I change the size of that terminal, `cols` always set to `72` and can't stretch to current resized terminal window.

I run `stty cols 72 && w3m https://google.com`, so I need to reset `stty cols` back to last state of terminal window.

I do have `stty` set in `~/.zshrc` that enables some options, too.

Comment: @roaima: e.g: I run `stty cols 72 && w3m https://google.com`, so I need to reset `stty cols` back to last state of terminal window. I do have `stty` set in `~/.zshrc` that enable some options only.

Answer (score 5):

Blindly answering the question you've asked, you can save the current column width and then restore it like this

```
c=$(tput cols)    # Save the columns
stty cols 72      # Change the characteristics temporarily
#...
stty cols $c      # Restore the saved width
```

But I would have to ask why you need to perform `stty cols 72` at all. You're using an `xterm`, so it should notify its process leader (i.e. the shell) automatically of any change when you resize it.